# Como vincular uma folha de estilo diferente da folha de estilo do template base em django

Tags: html, css, django

Digamos que temos o seguinte template como base de um projeto em django (Que aqui sera chamado de **base.html**):

```
{% load staticfiles %}

<html lan="pt-br">
  <head>     
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'base/style.css' %}" />
  </head>
  <body>
    {% block content %}
    {% endblock %}              
  </body>
</html>
```

Esse templante tem lincado uma folha de estilo css em seu head que contem as configurações básicas do template .

Logo abaixo temos um exemplo de template que herda do template basico (chamado de **form.html**):

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load staticfiles %}

    {% block content %}

    <form class="form" method="post">
      {% csrf_token %}
      {{ form }} 
      <button type="submit" >Cadastrar</button>
    </form>

    {% endblock content %}
```

Sendo que o template **form.html** e um bloco no body do **base.html** e não possui head,  como e possível vincular uma folha de estilo exclusiva para os componentes    do **form.html** e ainda manter a compatibilidade da folha de estilo anterior ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primeiro no seu **base.html** crie um novo bloco dentro da tag head:

```
<head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
            href="{% static "appfolder/css/base.css" %}" />
        {% block novobloco %}{% endblock %}
    </head>
```

Agora, chame ele dentro do seu template, passando o arquivo para o bloco:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
    {% load static %}

    {% block novobloco %}
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
        href="{% static "arquivo.css" %}" />
    {% endblock %}

    {% block content %}
      main
    {% endblock %}
```